# useReducer and useContext Dispatch doesn't work in onClick function

Tags: reactjs, dispatch, use-context, use-reducer

I'll spare you the broader context as it's pretty simple. Using React hooks, the first dispatch here fires automatically and works just fine, but the second one doesn't. `Context` is imported from another file, so I assume it's a (lowercase) context issue, but I don't know how to fix it?

```
const Component = props => {
  const [, dispatch] = useContext(Context);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = state.title;
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  });

  // this works
  dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_TITLE", payload: "Not Click!" });

  function onAddClick() {
    // this doesn't work
    dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_TITLE", payload: "CLICKED!" });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <AddButton onClick={onAddClick} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here's the parent.

```
const Reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "UPDATE_TITLE":
      state["title"] = action.payload;
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const initialState = {
  title: "My Title"
};

export const Context = createContext(initialState);

const App = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(Reducer, initialState);

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>
      <Component />
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Console logs fire in the correct reducer case in both cases, but only the one marked 'this works' will actually update the state properly, the other one fails silently.

---

Fixed: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-wescoff-9epf9?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Can you give me more details? Did you try to put some logging inside `onAddClick` to make sure that it's running?

Comment: Yeah, it's running alright. The dispatched case in the reducer switch gets called as well. But the state changes don't happen when it's called from the click, whereas they DO happen when it's called in the LayoutSystem initializer. 

I added some more code for context.

Comment: `LayoutSystem` → `Component` (I updated the code example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are attempting to mutate state directly. Instead try to return a new object that is the result of the changes from the action applied to the old state.

```
const Reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "UPDATE_TITLE":
      return {
        ...state,
        page: {
          ...state.page,
          title: action.payload
        }
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

[image: Edit mystifying-hofstadter-xqwy6]

---

Alternatively, use [produce from immerjs](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/produce) to give you the ability to write your reducer in this *mutable* style.

```
import produce from "immer";

const Reducer = produce((state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "UPDATE_TITLE":
      state["title"] = action.payload;
      break;
    default:
      return;
  }
});
```

[image: Edit reducer with immerjs produce]

Comment: That doesn't fix it, I'm afraid.

Comment: Ok. Consider creating a reproducible example to better get to the bottom of your issue.

Comment: That DID fix it, I just had to come at it from a slightly different angle (`Object.assign`) due to the depth of my state object. Thanks! Here's my final example, working. https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-wescoff-9epf9?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you trying to achieve by placing the `dispatch` outside `controlled` env (like an `event` or `useEffect`):-

```
// this works
dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_TITLE", payload: "Not Click!" });
// but it will run in infinite loop tho (no changes can be made then)
```

So the **fixes** should be:-

1. in `Reducer`, make sure not to completely `mutate` your `state`:-

```
const Reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "UPDATE_TITLE":
      // Don't do this
      // let newState = state;
      // newState["page"]["title"] = action.payload;
      // console.log("updating", newState, newState.page.title);
      // return newState;

      // Do this instead
      return {
        ...state,
        page: {
          ...state.page,
          title: action.payload
        }
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

2. Place your `dispatch` for `not Click!` inside an `event` or `function` or better yet in this case, `useEffect` since you wanna apply it `once` the `component` rendered.

```
const Demo = props => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useContext(Context);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = state.title;
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

    // this works (should be here)
    dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_TITLE", payload: "Not Click!" });
  }, []); // run it once when render

  // this works but, (should not be here tho - cause it will run non-stop)
  // dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_TITLE", payload: "Not Click!" });

  function onAddClick() {
    // this will work now
    dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_TITLE", payload: "CLICKED!" });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onAddClick}>Click Me!</button>
      <p>State now: {state.title}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

You can try and refer to this [sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kpchjo?file=src%2FDemo.js) and see how it works.

EDITED & UPDATED [sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dispatch-test-8raqxh?file=src%2FButton.js)

Comment: This is great, thank you. Will this work if the state has to go to another file though? That's my actual setup, that's why there's no expression of state in the file registering the click (I'm working on a hosted example).

Comment: Here's the example code. https://stackblitz.com/edit/dispatch-test?file=src/App.js

Comment: Follow the **Fixes no.1**. Since you got `nested` `obj` of `initialState`, then you should do like that.

Comment: you can see the updated [sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dispatch-test-8raqxh?file=src%2FButton.js) to see it working